# Is there any CallBack function which is called before/after data is loaded in Angular Js ng-Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Presently i have a Angular Js Grid which is pagination Enabled say 5 records per page for example and total number of records is 2000, so there are going to be 400 pages in All.

when pagination in ng-grid is handled the gridOption data is specified per page which means for 1st page the gridOption will be 1-5 rows for 2nd 6-10 rows and so on........

Here i have implemented a selection functionality through checkboxes thus whenever a row is selected[checkBox becomes selected] and it's stored in selectedItems array and i show selected items in another grid like this.....

[image: page 1 where two rows are selected]

Now when i move on to second page[pagination] and select further rows like this ...

[image: page two here now total three records are selected]

The real trouble lies here when i again go back to the previous page i.e page 1 the checkboxes will not be checked because in pagination we load data runtime thus the pages shows following result...

[image: the selection here disappears due to dynamic nature of pagination]

Hope you must have understood my problem....

what i need here is a callback before/after data is loaded so that i can select the checkboxes as i have the number of selection preserved

OR any other workaround for my problem will be much helpful too.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store the checked value on the data model where you are storing the row values? Then you come back and its just checked by Angular bindings?

I am not sure of your setup, but I do this in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this for a couple days now.

While I am still unable to preserve selection across pagination, I am able to clear selections while simultaneously "deselecting" the select all checkbox.

The allSelected variable is not exposed in the gridScope but you are able to grab it and address it using the following code.

```
        // Use this to deselect all options.
        $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.toggleSelectAll(null, false);
        // use this to find the allSelected variable which is tied to the 
        // (the ng-model related to the select all checkbox in the header row)
        var header = angular.element(".ngSelectionHeader").scope();
        // use this to turn off the checkbox.
        header.allSelected = false;
```

I'll follow up again if I manage to get the "reselecting" to work as documented, but for now I might remain content with this.